# Run mist without downloading blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, parity, synchronization, light-clients

How do I prevent `mist` from ever downloading the blockchain?

I have a small HDD and can't afford the disk space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using `parity`

You can have `parity` emulate `geth`'s IPC (ie, pretend to be `geth`), by running:

```
parity --light --geth
```

If you want to be lazy, you can add to your [configuration file](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity):

```
[parity]
light = true
geth = true
```

---

Then start mist as:

```
mist  --syncmode light
```

If you get a blank screen when `mist` loads, see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Using-Parity-with-Mist).

Answer (score 5):

#### Using`geth`

Running `geth --light` will not download the blockchain, but instead query other nodes for any information contained in the blockchain.

It took me quite a bit of investigation to work out how to use `mist` with `geth --light`, but the answer is to first start `geth`:

```
geth --light
```

Then start mist, telling it to use the node in light mode:

```
mist  --syncmode light
```

You *should* be able to just run `mist --node-light`, but [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2899) is currently preventing it.

As a work-around for linux users, based on [@pparent76's script](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2372#issuecomment-318395351), I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Work around for issues:
# https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2254
# https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2372
# https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2999
set -eu # For script robustness
geth=$(which geth)
mist=$(which mist) # Change to explicit path if you call this script "mist"

# Use pidof as procps' pgrep is broken:
# sleep 1& pgrep -ax '^sleep$' should return null
if ! geth_pid=$(pidof geth); then
  echo "Starting $geth."
  "$geth" --syncmode light &
else
  echo "Geth is already running with PID(s): $geth_pid"
fi

if ! mist_pid=$(pidof mist); then
  echo "Starting $mist."
  "$mist" --light-node
else
  echo "Mist is already running with PID(s): $mist_pid"
fi
```

Call the script "emist" so it doesn't recursively call itself :)

---

**Bonus safety seatbelt:**

Since [geth doesn't support a startup file](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2067), you may want to ensure that geth will not start without using `--light`.

Ensure geth cannot create a lock file on the blockchain database:

```
rm -rf ~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ && mkdir -m 000 ~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/
```

This will remove any already downloaded blockchain data, and recreate the directory without write permissions.

In Windows, you can remove the write permissions for the current user by right-clicking on the chaindata directory, selecting "Properties" then "Permissions" and unticking "write" permissions for the current user.

If I then try to run `geth` without `--light`, I get:

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: open /home/ravi/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/LOCK: permission denied
```

This is desirable because it:

- Prevents any blockchain download
- Reminds me to run `geth` with `--light`
- Ensures that I don't need clean up any partially downloaded blockchain data.